# C# Changing Button Text Automatically from another Form

Tags: c#, forms, button, text

I'm creating a Windows application. On the Form I have 3 Buttons that will become user configurable from a Setup Menu. I have created a Second Form as a Popup where the user can add the relevent information for each button. When they Click "Done" on this Popup form I want to update the Button Text on Form 1.

```
public string ButtonVNC1Text
{
    get
    {
        return btn1VNC.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        this.btn1VNC.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then on Form 2 when the Done Button is pressed I have the Following Code.

```
private void btn1VNCSetup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Collect Entered Data
    VNCVars.VNC1Description = txtVNC1Des.Text;
    //Update Button Text
    BespakHMI main = new BespakHMI();
    main.ButtonVNC1Text = txtVNC1Des.Text;
    //Save the Data that has been entered into the Setup Fields for VNC1/2/3
    SaveXML.SaveData();
    this.Close(); // closes the Form2 instance.
}
```

But when Form 2 Close's the Text hasnt been updated. If I add a button on Form 1 and do the Following then the text does change.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonVNC1Text = VNCVars.VNC1Description;
}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
// Update Button Text
BespakHMI main = new BespakHMI();
main.ButtonVNC1Text = txtVNC1Des.Text;
```

you are not updating the **existing** `BespakHMI` form, but a **new** invisible instance.

One way to resolve is to **find** the existing form like this

```
var main = Application.OpenForms.OfType<BespakHMI>().FirstOrDefault();
if (main != null)
{
    main.ButtonVNC1Text = txtVNC1Des.Text;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to pass form1 in the constructor of form 2

step1 :
instead of

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

use

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);//You give to form2 the 'address' of form1 by using 'this'
```

step2 :
write the following in Form2:

```
Form1 creator = null;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    creator = form1;//the 'this aka address of form1' is saved in the creator variable
}
```

step 3:
use

```
creator.btn1VNC.Text = "hello there";// sets btn1VNC in the original form to "hello there" in form 2, using the address of form 2.
```